# How do i code review in tfs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have 3 levels of users in my Team Foundation Server:

1. **Programmer**: A code reviewer must review their code and they cannot check in their own code
2. **Professional Programmer**: Their code doesn't need to be reviewed but a copy of their code should be automatically sent to a code reviewer
3. **Code Reviewer**: Their code doesn't need to be reviewed and can be checked in directly

How can i implement this ?

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to use Branches and Alerts. For example...

- Senior programmers would work directly on your "main" branch so they can check code into the live codebase.
- Junior programmers would work on the "RequiresReview" branch, and then the code reviewers would review their check-ins and merge them into Main only when they are satisfied with the code.

TFS can send email Alerts for various events, so the code reviewers could just subscribe to the check-in events to know when code has been checked into Main (by a Senior programmer) or needs to be reviewed (has been checked into RequiresReview by a Junior Programmer)

The use of branches in this way would mean that you would have to merge in both directions (merge junior's checkins across to Main, and merge senior's checkins back into RequiresReview)

Another approach for Junior Programmers is to use ShelveSets instead of another branch. In this approach, Juniors would not check in their code, but would simply move it into a shelveset and then email the code reviewer to request that their shelveset is reviewed and checked in for them. This avoids the need for merging code from Main back into RequiresReview - the juniors would be working "on" the Main branch, but their checkins would be "gated" via the shelveset.

There are also some 3rd party tools you can purchase to manage code review processes for you in a much more integrated manner. A web search should help you find these sort of tools.

**edit**
*Please note that Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 now include integrated support for code reviews (essentially a proper user interface on top of the shelveset idea above), so upgrading from 2010 may be a better option than my suggested workarounds above.*

Comment: thanks for your help .. can i create 3 group of users in active Directory and then get group name of user that use checkin command in checkin policy code and then Decide for that operation?
for example : if (groupname=="Programmers") {aivect code review operation } else if(groupname=="codereviewer") {chickin} etc... can implement this? if answer is true  how to get groupname and how to active codeReview operation? thanks for youe help...

Comment: Each user can be given different permissions, so for example, if you don't want juniors to check in, you can simply put them in a group that doesn't have check-in rights. Notifications can be handled by automatic Alert emails (or by a procedure of juniors mailing a request for review of their shelvesets, if you go for that approach). Searching on these subjects will turn up a lot of information about how each part can be implemented. But note that with most programmers, simply telling them the process they are required to use is enough to get a system that works well.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this mostly in TFS 2010, but there is no easy way to expose this from the UI. TFS 2012 and VS2012 will provide a much better UI for code review and it has an embedded process which will take you through he hoops.

If you want to configure Source control permissions as you've described, this is how it would work:

> ### Programmers
>
> Stick them in a TFS group or AD group and set their security so that they have Checkout and Lock permissions on their working branch, but no check-in permissions. When they're done with their work have them create a shelveset and then let them send an email to the reviewer with the shelveset name. The reviewer either returns the set with comments (either inline or through email or workitems) or he checks the code in on behalf of the programmer. because the programmers don't check in directly, you can't set up an automatic alert. You could alter the process template to include ready for review as a state for a task and have them transition the task (it's how the custom code review solutions tend to work).
>
> ### Code Reviewer
>
> Must at least have checkout, lock and check in rights. Stick them in a TFS group or an AD group and set the security accordingly. They can check in directly without the need to use shelvesets.
>
> ### Professional Programmers
>
> (I'd be careful with this term, it would make the other programmers sound unprofessional, I'd prefer senior or seasoned). Give them the same permissions as the Code Reviewer. [Configure a TFS Alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx) which goes off when anyone in this group check something in. Send the alert to the Code Reviewers. They can then use the View History option to review the Changeset and send comments to the programmer in question. Use the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx) to make configuring the alerts a lot easier (and more powerful).

If you want a more advanced solution, one that integrates into the TFS process template, then you can use one of these two open source solutions:

- [TeamReview](http://teamreview.codeplex.com/)
- [TFS Code Review Worlflow](http://tfscodereviewflow.codeplex.com/)

Or look at their code (they're open source) to get an idea on how you could build something like this yourself. It's not going to be very easy though, and it would probably be useless once TFS 2012 comes out.

Also check out [my presentation on the new features in TFS 2012 around code review](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/03/did-you-miss-my-techdaysnl-talk-on-code.html) (the ppt is in English, though the recording was done at a Dutch conference and thus in Dutch).

Answer (score 2):

+1 Jason
one of the good 3rd party is team review

http://teamreview.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks M.Radwan. it is a tool but how can i implement that myself? can get group name or user name that use checkin operation in custom checkin policy code?

Comment: I don't get your point? but as I see, there are aloft of solutions from all fellows here, try anyone of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to Visual Studio 2012,  then there is a great code review interface built right into the Team Explorer UI now (Requires TFS 2012 as well).  Check it out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/09/04/new-code-review-feature-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx